# Programmatic auto attendant on an Android device

Tags: android, iphone, ios

Is it possible to create an Android application that automatically attend incoming calls to an Android phone? If so, which APIs may be used to achieve this (a piece of code snippet highly appreciable)?

If the programmatic auto attendant feature not possible, why the Android OS imposes this restriction?

Is iOS behaves as same as Android in this scenario, please explain.

Answer (score 1):

While googling I found something that can be useful. I haven't tried yet still I think this will help have a look at [**Call Control in Android**](http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.in/2010/09/call-control-in-android.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can listen incomming call intent by implementing broadcast receiver `Intent.CALL_STATE_CHANGED` to listen for incoming call, but answering incomming call automatically seems not feasible.coz android application dont have access to incomming call audio stream.

Comment: I searched myself and find Intent.ACTION_ANSWER, is this doing the magic?